# separate line in words by slash and use /W but avoid :

Tags: python, parsing, space, slash

i am trying to parse a txt file with a lot of lines like this:

```
470115572 cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN/CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_7/branchController00/easyCrate3/easyBoard16/channel003
```

i am making a dictionary where the key is the first number on the line, and the values are (for each key) the words separated by the slash `"/"`, every one of this words is saved into a list, for example `list1` gets all `cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN`, `list2` would be all `CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_7`, etc

but when i use      `pattern = re.split('\W',line)` to split the line, it takes into account
the `":"` character, i mean when i try to print `cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN` it only returns `cms_trk_dcs_05`, how can i save in the list all the word `cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN`, and save in my list all the words separated by slash

I am new at python, so i apologize if this is for dummys
anyway thank you in advance

Comment: The RegEx metachar `\W` determines any non-word character, and `:` (colon) is a non-word character.  Why don't match simply the `/` char ?

Comment: i used SiHa's idea, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to match first the space after the number, and then the '/':

```
>>> stringin = "470115572 cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN/CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_7/branchController00/easyCrate3/easyBoard16/channel003"
>>> splitstring = stringin.split(' ')
>>> num = splitstring[0]
>>> stringlist = splitstring[1].split('/')
>>> num
'470115572'
>>> stringlist
['cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN', 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_7', 'branchController00', 'easyCrate3', 'easyBoard16', 'channel003']
>>>
```

Or as a (less obvious) one-liner:

```
>>> [x.split('/') for x in stringin.split(' ')]

[['470115572'], ['cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN', 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_7', 'branchController00', 'easyCrate3', 'easyBoard16', 'channel003']]
```

Note, though, that the second approach creates the first element as a list.

Comment: thanks, but how can i put all cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN (the files is made of a lot of lines like the one in my question) in just one list, and CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_7 in another list, etc

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this bit. Could you update your question with, say 3-4 lines, and the structure of the required result? As I understand it at the moment, each key would have a list of seven lists, each with one element. This is not what you want, I think.

Comment: I solved with a little modification of your first idea , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As in Trimax's comment: `:` (colon) is a nonword character, so to split line correctly you need to include it in pattern. Or use SiHa's answer.

About pattern, `\W` equals to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), so you can just add colon to it: `[^a-zA-Z0-9_:]`

As for second part, just use first element of result list as dict key and assign remained list to it in form of slice.
Something like this:

```
    result_dict = {}
    for line in file_lines:
        line_splitted = re.split('[^a-zA-Z0-9_:]+', line)
        result_dict[line_splitted[0]] = line_splitted[1:]
```

Note though, if your text contains lines with same numbers, you'll lose data, as when assigning new value (list of words in this case) to existing key, it will overwrite previous value.

Comment: there are not repeated keys, and i used SiHa answer to solve it!! but thank you for your answer!